# paramiko issue with host keys - BadHostKeyException

Tags: python, paramiko

Here is the script that I am using to connect to an SFTP server. `sftp.pem` and `host.pem` are private keys in OpenSSH format. I created the user and added the host key to the server myself.

I keep getting an error with this approach (see error message below). I can log in successfully if I add `client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())`. But my understanding is that it is not a good practice.

What is the proper way to connect to the SFTP server with private keys?

```py
import paramiko


private_key_path = "./sftp.pem"
host_key_path = "./host.pem"
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
hostname = '##.###.##.#'
username = 'username'

key_obj = paramiko.RSAKey(filename=host_key_path)
client.get_host_keys().add(hostname, "ssh-rsa", key_obj)

client.connect(hostname=hostname,
               username=username,
               key_filename=private_key_path)
```

**ERROR**

> paramiko.ssh_exception.BadHostKeyException: Host key for server
> '##.###.##.#' does not match: got
> 'AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQ...+jCkEL', expected
> 'AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQ...feZ6l'

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be a misunderstanding regarding the usage of **paramiko.RSAKey**. The **paramiko.RSAKey** class is typically used for the client's private key, not the server's host key. If you want to specify the client's private key, you should use the key_filename parameter directly in the **`connect`** method.

Here

```
import paramiko

private_key_path = "./sftp.pem"
hostname = '##.###.##.#'
username = 'username'

client = paramiko.SSHClient()

# Load the private key for the client
private_key = paramiko.RSAKey(filename=private_key_path)

# Automatically add the server's host key (this is not recommended for production)
# client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# Connect to the SFTP server
client.connect(
    hostname=hostname,
    username=username,
    pkey=private_key  # Use the private key for authentication
)

# Now you can perform SFTP operations using the 'client' object

# Close the connection when done
client.close()
```

This **pkey** parameter in the **connect** method specifies the client's private key directly. Also, note that the **set_missing_host_key_policy** line has been commented out. While using AutoAddPolicy can be convenient during development, it's not recommended for production environments as it exposes the client to potential man-in-the-middle attacks.

Make sure **sftp.pem** corresponds to the user you are trying to authenticate as on the SFTP server. If you continue to face issues, double-check that the private key and the server host key are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting indicates that the host key you are using does not match the one that the server expects.
Try this approach:

```
import paramiko

private_key_path = "./sftp.pem"
host_key_path = "./host.pem"
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
hostname = '##.###.##.#'
username = 'username'

client.load_system_host_keys(host_key_path)
client.connect(hostname=hostname,
               username=username,
               key_filename=private_key_path)
sftp = client.open_sftp()
```

This method uses the load_system_host_keys to load the host key file directly into the client’s host keys.
This is also simpler and more convenient, as you do not need to create a key object manually.
This will also create an instance of the SFTPClient class, which allows you to perform various operations on the remote files and directories.